# Ambiguous port publish parameters to "docker run"

Tags: docker

Docker's shipyard project has a prebuilt container to simplify running its components. It's simply just a *run* script that launches and links several other containers.

However, I find their usage of the port-publish parameter (-p) confusing in two of the *run* commands:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d -p 80 --link shipyard_redis:redis --name shipyard_router shipyard/router

sudo docker run -i -t -d -p 80:80 --link shipyard_redis:redis --link shipyard_router:app_router --name shipyard_lb shipyard/lb
```

The first command passes a single parameter to "-p", which doesn't seem legal, since every official usage is suppose to have at least two, colon-separated parts:

```
  -p, --publish=[]           Publish a container's port to the host
                               format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort
                               (use 'docker port' to see the actual mapping)
```

The second command is confusing because it seems like this would cause a port collision with the container started in the first command.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: The first command is valid.  It will map port 80 to a random public port i.e. 0.0.0.0->some_random_port.  You can see that by running `docker ps` after the two said commands.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify -p with only 1/single port number. Docker automatically assigns a random port mapping (usually starting from port 49150) to the single port exposed in the container ie. 80

what this means is, lets say you run Apache 2 on port 80 inside your container. Then you will have to point your browser to localhost:49150 to access your Apache web server.